# Tailwind background image from api

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to solve this one but have no luck. I am getting image-urls from API, and I want to put it as BG using tailwind but it doesn't work for me.

```
 <div
    className={`w-full h-60 rounded-2xl bg-cover bg-center bg-[url('${item.image}')]`}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using tailwind use style prop:

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage : ‘url(“${item.image}”)‘ }}></div>
```